# Generate functions in which have more than one line of code

Tags: python, mysql, function, tkinter

My code actually goes like:
more code behind

```
        names = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()
        names.execute('SELECT _name FROM items')
        item_name = names.fetchall()
        i = 0
        distance = 0
        name = 1
        for item in item_name:
            for j in range(len(item)):
                buttoncommandstr = "generatebuttoncommand{}".format(i)
                print(buttoncommandstr)
                result_button = eval('self.' + buttoncommandstr)

                fontanierabutton = ctk.CTkButton(self, text=str(item[j]), width=200, height=20,
                                                 fg_color='grey',
                                                 bg_color='white',
                                                 corner_radius=5,
                                                 text_color='black', font=("Arial bold", 20),
                                                 command=lambda: result_button(name))
                fontanierabutton.place(x=80, y=distance)
                print(name)
            i = i + 1
            name = name + 1
            distance = distance + 40

    def generatebuttoncommand0(self, x):
        print(x)
        return x

    def generatebuttoncommand1(self, x):
        print(x)

    def generatebuttoncommand2(self, x):
        print(x)

    def generatebuttoncommand3(self, x):
```

etc.

But i have to do the "def generatebuttoncommand{num} be generated depending on the items i have in the sql database. But! You'll say i could easily succeed that by doing a second new "for" like

```
   names = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()
   names.execute('SELECT _name FROM items')
   item_name = names.fetchall()
   i = 0
   distance = 0
   name = 1
   for item in item_name:
        for j in range(len(item)):
             exec(f"def generatebuttoncommand{i}(): ...")
        i = i + 1
```

this would generate functions but i could only add, maximum of 10 lines , but the code i want to add on every button is more like 80 lines with new buttons and new "command" calls on them.

The result i would like to have is:
(having 10 items in my sql table)

(item 1 button) ---> Label with (_name , _cost , _price , _category) on seperate boxes and get a new button of ---> Updating the sql data if i want to change any of these columns

(item 2 button) ---> Label with (_name2 , _cost2 , _price2 , _category2) on seperate boxes and get a new button of ---> Updating the sql data if i want to change any of these columns

and then if i add a new item it will generate all those functions and buttons automaticaly.

I did try another way of generating buttons depending on the sql database but i got other error from that

```
CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()
        CallDB.execute('SELECT * FROM items')
        items_ID3 = CallDB.fetchall()
        
        i = 1
        distance = 0
        for item in items_ID3:
            for j in range(len(item)):
                print("hi")
                query_name = 'SELECT _name FROM items WHERE iditems=%s'
                query_ID = 'SELECT iditems FROM items WHERE iditems=%s'

                item_NAME = CallDB.execute(query_name, (i,))
                print(item_NAME)
                items_ID = CallDB.execute(query_ID, (i,))
                self.MakeButtonsForItems(item_NAME, distance, items_ID)

            i = i + 1
            distance = distance + 40


    def MakeButtonsForItems(self, buttonname, distance, buttonid):
        buttonGenerator = ctk.CTkButton(self, text=buttonname, width=200, height=20,
                                         fg_color='grey',
                                         bg_color='white',
                                         corner_radius=5,
                                         text_color='black', font=("Arial bold", 20),
                                         command=lambda: self.genaratebuttoncommand0(buttonid))
        buttonGenerator.place(x=80, y=distance)
```

error is
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\katsi\PycharmProjects\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test3.py", line 173, in 
app = BaseWindow()
File "C:\Users\katsi\PycharmProjects\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test3.py", line 63, in **init**
items_ID = CallDB.execute(query_ID, (i,))
File "C:\Users\katsi\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 303, in execute
self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
File "C:\Users\katsi\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 921, in handle_unread_result
raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found "

Comment: You can write string literals with arbitrary amount of lines if they start and end with triple quotes `'''` or `"""`. Maybe I don't understand your problem correctly.

Comment: You're making things way too difficult. Why do you think you need to create a separate function for every button, instead of a single function that takes arguments? A really, really good rule of thumb is "don't use exec". While it has its uses, this isn't one of them.

Comment: you can definitely loop through function(s) and buttons, data, names, costs, etc. to make your life easier.

Comment: do all the `generatebuttoncommandX()` methods do conceptually the same thing? Perhaps you only need one of these that might be passed some meta data to do the right thing.

Comment: Are the functions supposed to be the same? The first one has `return x`, the others don't. The last one doesn't have any body at all.

Comment: It all depends on what the functions do

Comment: @bryanoakley  i do accept what you say , i just need some help with that because i am stuck. do you have any example on your mind ?

Comment: @jonsg i just added it for testings , its just a part of the code , just an example to use that's why its not completed

Comment: @bryanOakley check what i added in the end of this post,  should it be that way ?

Comment: Focus on one specific problem and one specific implementation, and edit the question for that. Why did you change the code for querying from the database? And you didn't describe what task should be done in the handlers of buttons. Also post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did

```
        CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()
        CallDB.execute('SELECT * FROM items')
        items_ID3 = CallDB.fetchall()
        print(items_ID3)
        i = 1
        distance = 0
        for item in items_ID3:
            get_name = get_NameOfItem(i)
            get_ID = get_IDOfItem(i)
            self.MakeButtonsForItems(get_ID, get_name, distance)

            i = i + 1
            distance = distance + 40

    def MakeButtonsForItems(self, buttonid, buttonname, distance):
        ButtonVariable = buttonid
        buttonGenerator = ctk.CTkButton(self, text=buttonname, width=200, height=20,
                                        fg_color='grey',
                                        bg_color='white',
                                        corner_radius=5,
                                        text_color='black', font=("Arial bold", 20),
                                        command=lambda: self.genaratebuttoncommand0(ButtonVariable))
        buttonGenerator.place(x=80, y=distance)

    def genaratebuttoncommand0(self, Item_id):
        ...
```

and made these functions for getting the info from the sql database

```
def get_IDOfItem(VarForPick):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT iditems FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (VarForPick,))

    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_ID = stage_set[2:-3]
    return int(Item_ID)


def get_NameOfItem(ID_item):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT _name FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (ID_item,))

    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_Name = stage_set[3:-4]
    return str(Item_Name)


def get_PriceOfItem(Price_item):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT _price FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (Price_item,))
    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_ID = stage_set[2:-3]
    return float(Item_ID)


def get_CostOFItem(Cost_item):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT _cost FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (Cost_item,))
    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_Cost = stage_set[2:-3]
    return float(Item_Cost)


def get_CategoryOfItem(Category_item):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT _category FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (Category_item,))
    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_Category = stage_set[3:-4]
    return str(Item_Category)


def get_StockOfItem(Stock_item):
    CallDB = aoracandlestudiodb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT _stock FROM items WHERE iditems= %s '
    CallDB.execute(query, (Stock_item,))
    stage_get = CallDB.fetchall()
    stage_set = str(stage_get)
    Item_Stock = stage_set[2:-3]
    return int(Item_Stock)
```